# every root of unity $x$ determines a degree one representation of $G$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I was told that if $G=\langle g \rangle$ is a cyclic group then every root of unity $x$ determines a degree one representation of $G$. But what is this representation? $\rho(x)=?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is only $n$th roots of unity, where $g$ has order $n$. Then $\rho(g)=(\zeta)$ for $\zeta$ an $n$th root of unity is the representation.

Comment: What is $(\zeta)$?

Comment: $\zeta$ is an nth root of unity, as stated in the answer. $(\zeta)$ is the $1\times 1$-matrix with entry $\zeta$.

Comment: So basically with this I can compute the character table of any cyclic group $C_n$ right?

Comment: Yep. It's just lots of powers of some fixed primitive $n$th root $\zeta_n$ of $1$, normally $\zeta_n=\mathrm{e}^{2\pi\mathrm{i}/n}$. If $\chi_i$ is the character afforded by $\rho_i:g\mapsto (\zeta_n^i)$ then the character table is given by $\chi_i(g^j)=\zeta_n^{ij}$.

Answer (score 1):

Formally, if $\zeta$ is $n$th-root of unity and $|G|=n$ then we can define the representation $\rho:G\to GL(\mathbb{C})$ by $\rho(g^k)(z)=\zeta^kz$ for $0\leq k\leq n-1$. It is well defined, because $\zeta^n=1$.

Comment: What is $z$ meant to be?

Comment: A complex number. $\rho(g^k)$ is an invertible linear transformation $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Normally representations are defined in terms of matrices. This is, I think, the first time I've ever seen a representation defined as a linear transformation. I'm not saying it isn't valid, just highly unusual.

Comment: My definition of a representation in a field $F$ is a group homomorphism $\rho:G\to GL(V)$ where $V$ is a vector space over $F$. As I know this is the standard definition. If $V$ is finite dimensional then after choosing a specific basis this naturally gives us a homomorphism $G\to GL_n(F)$ where $n$ is the dimension. Since in the case of finite groups most of the interesting representations are finite dimensional then one can indeed prefer to work with matrices. I usually feel more comfortable with transformations. After all, most vector spaces don't have a "natural" basis.

Comment: As I said, I'm not saying you aren't correct in defining a representation as being given by a linear transformation, it is perfectly valid. I am just saying that literally everyone else I have ever seen write down a representation uses matrices.